# How to show only the nodes connected to the ones selected using Cypher of Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to see only the nodes labeled ':Context' that are connected to all (or the maximum) number of the nodes labeled ':Concept'.

I'm currently using a query:

`match (c:Concept), (ctx:Context), (c)-[r]->(ctx) where (c.name = 'italy' or c.name = 'pick') return ctx,c;`

This gives out the following result:

[image]

How would I remove all the unnecessary green nodes (they are the ones of the ':Context' type) and only leave those, which are connected both to "pick" and "italy" :Concept nodes?

I also want to be able to perform the same search for 3 nodes and more. Can't understand what's the best way to do that (with or without APOC).

This query below works:

`match (c1:Concept{name:"italy"})-->(ctx:Context)<--(c2:Concept{name:"pick"}) return ctx;`

but only for 2 items. What if I want to do the same for 3 or more?

this one is too slow:
`match (c1:Concept{name:"italy"})-->(ctx:Context)<--(c2:Concept{name:"pick"})-->(ctx:Context)<--(c3:Concept{name:"novice"}) return ctx;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match as many branches as you want in additional matches like this

```
match (c1:Concept{name:"italy"})-->(ctx:Context)<--(c2:Concept{name:"pick"})
match (c3:Concept{name:"france"})-->(ctx)
return ctx;
```

Although, I would recommend using [params](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) as they are more reusable. So assuming you have the param 'list' that contains `["italy", france", "pick"]`

```
MATCH (c:Concept)
WHERE c.name in $list
WITH COLLECT(c) as concepts
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE ALL(c in concepts WHERE (c)-->(ctx))
RETURN ctx
```

Comment: Thank you! And how to create a param "list"?

Comment: Found the answer: MATCH (c:Concept)
WHERE c.name in (["italy","pick","novice"])  
WITH COLLECT(c) as concepts
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE ALL(c in concepts WHERE (c)-->(ctx))
RETURN ctx

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin I fixed the syntax, and added a link to how to use Neo4j Parameters. (The previous syntax worked, but is deprecated for the new one) In the browser, you can set params using `:params`. Use `params help` for more info.